# Difference between variable with or without $ in Angular 4

Tags: angular, redux

I have been trying to understand the difference between the variables created with or without $. 
For Example
In @ngrx/store we declare Actions like

```
export class SomeEffectClass {
    constructor(**private actions$ : Actions**) {}
}
```

Is the below code similar in functionality as above

```
export class SomeEffectClass {
    constructor(**private actions : Actions**) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact same code. It's just a convention you can use, such as underscores like _actions.

In this case, the dollar sign is used to indicate that your property is an Observable. [You can find it more here](https://cycle.js.org/basic-examples.html#basic-examples-increment-a-counter-what-is-the-convention)

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche. Appreciate your help